# Get pandas df column value distribution

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe from the values of another column. What I intend to obtain is from the column of goals per team, to distribute the goal count in an array of 10 positions. Where the `0` position of the array shows how many have scored between 0 and 10 goals and so on until the last position (9) that counts how many between 90 and 100.

For example:

From a dataframe like this one:

```
| player_id | team    | goals  |
|-----------|---------|--------|
| ply_1     | Arsenal | 100    |
| ply_2     | Arsenal | 2      |
| ply_3     | Chelsea | 21     | 
| ply_4     | Chelsea | 13     |  
| ply_5     | Arsenal | 50     |
```

Get one like the following:

```
| player_id | team    | goals | goals_distribution_by_team| 
|-----------|---------|-------|---------------------------|
| ply_1     | Arsenal | 100   | [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]     | 
| ply_2     | Arsenal | 2     | [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]     | 
| ply_3     | Chelsea | 21    | [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]     | 
| ply_4     | Chelsea | 13    | [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]     | 
| ply_5     | Arsenal | 50    | [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]     |
```

In this case we can see that for `Arsenal` team the number of goals are distributed for `0-10` (ply_2), `50-60` (ply_5) and `90-100` (ply_1).

So far I have achieved this by doing a `for` that goes through the goals column and checks if the number of goals is in which range.

```py
for goal in goals:
 if 0 < goal <=10:
    count()
 if 10 < goal <=20:
    count()
....
 if 90 < goal <=100:
    count()
```

Is there more pythonic way to achive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some workarounds I finally managed to find the proper solution using [Pandas.Cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function.

```
bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['goals'], bins=bins, labels=labels)

out = (df.groupby(['team'])['binned']
       .apply(lambda x: [int((i == x).sum()) for i in range(10)])
       )

df = df.reset_index().merge(out.rename('goals_distribution_by_team'), on=['team'])
df = df.drop(columns=['index', 'binned'])
```

```
print(df)

  player_id     team  goals         goals_distribution_by_team
0     ply_1  Arsenal    100  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1     ply_2  Arsenal      2  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
2     ply_3  Chelsea     21  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3     ply_4  Chelsea     13  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4     ply_5  Arsenal     50  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to group the dataframe by `team`, then apply a function to get those ones and zeroes as lists:

```py
out = (df.groupby('team')['goals']
        .apply(lambda x: [int((i==x//10).any()) for i in range(11)])
         )

team
Arsenal    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Chelsea    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Name: goals, dtype: object
```

Once you have it, you can merge it back to the original dataframe

```py
df.reset_index().merge(out.rename('goals_distribution_by_team'), on='team')

  player_id     team  goals         goals_distribution_by_team
0     ply_1  Arsenal    100  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1     ply_2  Arsenal      2  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
2     ply_5  Arsenal     50  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
3     ply_3  Chelsea     21  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4     ply_4  Chelsea     13  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Many thanks @ThePyGuy :) the thing is that if there are 2 goals that are under 0-10 range, instead of one should appear the value of 2

Comment: Hi again, I've found a bug in this solution... this lists has 11 positions and they need to be 10. Also I needed to add .sum() function instead of any() in order to make it sum all the goals under same "bucket".

Comment: the main problem is that if I do the range(0,10), for 100 goals there is not going to be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with divide column by integers division by `10`, then add `0` by missing range values in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandawheres.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), redistibute `1` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and last convert to lists:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies((df['goals'] // 10))
max1 = range(df1.columns.max() + 1)

df['goals_distribution_by_team'] = (df1.reindex(max1, axis=1, fill_value=0)
                                       .groupby(df['team']).transform('max')
                                       .to_numpy().tolist())
print (df)
  player_id     team  goals         goals_distribution_by_team
0     ply_1  Arsenal    100  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1     ply_2  Arsenal      2  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
2     ply_3  Chelsea     21  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3     ply_4  Chelsea     13  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4     ply_5  Arsenal     50  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```